# How to fix ERROR 713 & 702 in SIMCOM series 76xx

Tags: embedded, gsm, arduino-ide, gprs

```
AT+HTTPINIT
OK

AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://api.openw⸮athermap.org"
OK

AT+HTTPACTION=0
OK
+HTTPACTION: 0,713,0

AT+HTTPTERM
OK

---------------------------

AT+HTTPINIT
OK

AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://api.openw⸮
ERROR

AT+HTTPACTION=0
+HTTPACTION: 0,702,0
OK

AT+HTTPTERM
OK
```

I coding in Arduino IDE for SIMCom A7670C, I follow ["A76XX Series_HTTP(S)_Application Note_V1.03" datasheet](https://m5stack.oss-cn-shenzhen.aliyuncs.com/resource/docs/datasheet/module/sim7680/A76XX%20Series_HTTP(S)_Application%20Note_V1.02.pdf) and ["76xx AT Command" datasheet](https://www.waveshare.net/w/upload/6/68/SIM7500_SIM7600_Series_AT_Command_Manual_V2.00.pdf).

I have a problem with `HTTPACTION`, error code is 713 and 702. How should I solve it?

I used ESP8266 connect with SIMCom.

Comment: Since the error is emitted by the device in response to an AT Command I would say it is not a programming issue or coding error so off topic on this site.  The preceding command is emitting an error too - the URL looks malformed.  Is that not a concern?  Generally you should fix the errors in the order they occur in case one causes the other.

Comment: ... while editing your post I noted that the URL has an invalid character in it that is causing the rendering on the post to fail.  I am guessing that `http://api.openw⸮athermap.org` should be `http://api.openweathermap.org`?  Fix that issue first, because it is either causal or a distraction from your actual issue.

Comment: ... further I see that `AT+HTTPACTION=0` is an `HTTP GET` request - clearly it is not going to work with that invalid URL.  So I return to my first point - address errors from the top down, not the bottom up.